# Unexpected behaviour when parsing a string with optional Suffix in antlr4

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

I want to match multiple Functions to accept a comma-seperated List of placeholders and then the definition of a Unit, which is again seperated by a comma from the rest of the arguments. The text to parse would look like example 1: `"produkt([F1],[F2],EURO_CENT)"` or example 2:`"produkt([F1],[F2],EURO)"`

The grammar for this like i would expect it to work is this:

```
[...]

term: [...]
    | 'produkt(' placeholder ',' placeholder ',' UNIT ')' #MultUnit
    [...]
    | placeholder #PlaceholderTwo
    ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

LBRACK: '[';
RBRACK: ']';
PLACE: TEXT+ NUMBER?;

placeholder: LBRACK PLACE+ RBRACK;

[..]

UNIT: TEXT (('_' TEXT)*)?;

TEXT: ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+;//[a-zA-Z]+;

[...]
```

With this grammar example 1 works as expected but example 2 gives me the error *"line 1:18 mismatched input 'EURO' expecting UNIT"*. As i understand it this means that "EURO" itself does not match the pattern for UNIT but "EURO_CENT" does. I do not understand why this is the case because the pattern for UNIT says that the "_CENT" part is optional and only the first part is mandatory.
I also tried to give the UNIT some Prefix (in this case "Unit.") by changing the pattern for Unit to `UNIT: 'Unit.' TEXT ('_' TEXT)*;`
I changed the input string to `"produkt([F1],[F2],Unit.EURO)"` accordingly and this matches like a charme.
However the second approach is not very userfriendly since we have to add something (in our opinion) unnecessary to the input. So the question is: why does the first option not match as expected when the UNIT-String is a single word and is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `PLACE` and `UNIT` are mutually ambiguous for content that only matches `TEXT`. If the sample inputs are canonical, then change the `PLACE` rule to remove the ambiguity:

```
PLACE : TEXT+ NUMBER ;
```

Other possibilities include redefining `PLACE` as

```
PLACE : LBRACK TEXT+ NUMBER? RBRACK; // adjust other rules accordingly
```

adding a predicate to the rule:

```
PLACE : {followsLBRACK()}? TEXT+ NUMBER ;
```

and redefining `UNIT`:

```
UNIT: TEXT ( 'S' | ( '_' TEXT )+ ) ; // EUROS or EURO_CENT; similar for other units.
```

BTW, Antlr generally evaluates its grammars top-down, so mixing your rules as you have actually obfuscates the logic.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I changed the rule for UNIT before seeing this answer (without realizing why the other solution did not work). This all makes much more sense now...could you explain the last part of your answer a little bit more? I am new to ANTLR and want to prevent further mistakes like this if possible. (some reading material or a good-practice kind of thing would be optimal)